# Specify class of NA in R (for if_else, dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

In the `if_else()` function in `dplyr`, [it requires that both the if:TRUE  and if:FALSE elements are of the same class](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html).

I wish to return `NA` from my `if_else()` statement.

But e.g.

```
if_else(mtcars$cyl > 5, NA, 1)
```

returns

> Error: `false` has type 'double' not 'logical'

Because simply reading in `NA` is logical, and 1 is numeric (double).

Wrapping `as.numeric()` around the `NA` works fine: e.g.

```
if_else(mtcars$cyl > 5, as.numeric(NA), 1)
```

returns

> [1](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html) NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA  1  1  1 NA NA NA  1

As what I am hoping for.

But this feels kinda silly/unnecessary. Is there a better way of inputting `NA` as a "*numeric `NA`*" than wrapping it like this?

NB this only applies to the stricter `dplyr::if_else` not `base::ifelse`.

Comment: All elements in an atomic vector must be of the same type. NA is logical by default. Hadley's function must check for the same data type prior to running, but the base R function simply coerces the NA to fit with the other argument. See the help page `?"NA"` for a better understanding of what is going on with the NA. Also, check out the output of `ifelse(mtcars$cyl > 5, "this", 1)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use NA_real_

```
if_else(mtcars$cyl > 5, NA_real_, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

try the base function

```
ifelse(mtcars$cyl > 5, NA, 1)
```

Comment: Yes I know, thanks, see edit, I'm more interested in understanding this behaviour, rather than working around it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `if_else_` from the package `hablar`. It is as rigid as `if_else` from `dplyr` about types, but allows for generic NA. See,

```
library(hablar)

if_else_(mtcars$cyl > 5, NA, 1)
```